# Remix Run - fetch returning empty response

Tags: express, fetch, loader, remix

I am pretty new to Remix and am running it with an express server backend.

I have the following routes setup: routes -> apps -> underwriting -> $merchantId.
Here is my Loader Function inside of $merchantId.tsx:

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async (args: DataFunctionArgs) => {
  try {
    const { params } = args
    const { merchantId } = params // path param
    invariant(merchantId, 'merchantId path parameter must be defined')
    const headers = args.request.headers
    const cookie = headers.get('cookie')
    const merchantData = await loadMerchantInfo(cookie as string)
    console.log('merchantData:', merchantData)
    
    return {
      dba: 'Warner Bros',
      id: merchantId,
      name: 'Acme, Inc',
      requestedLoanAmount: 150000,
    } as UnderwritingMerchantInfo // hard coded return to keep the page working
  } catch (err) {
    captureException(`Loader Error: ${err}`)
    throw new Error(`Loader Error: ${err}`)
  }
}
```

Here is my fetch method:

```
const insecureAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
})
export const loadMerchantInfo = async (cookie: string, options?: any) => {
  const actualOptions = options
    ? {
        ...options,
      }
    : ({} as RequestInit)
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    actualOptions.agent = insecureAgent
    const headers = actualOptions.headers
      ? {
          ...options.headers,
          cookie,
          accept: 'application/json',
        }
      : {
          cookie,
          accept: 'application/json',
        }
    actualOptions.headers = headers
  }
  return await fetch(
    '[Internal URL] ',
    actualOptions,
  )
}
```

When I run it the console prints out a big Response object that has no body like this:

```
merchantData: Response {
  size: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: ReadableStream {
      _state: 'readable',
      _reader: undefined,
      _storedError: undefined,
      _disturbed: false,
      _readableStreamController: [ReadableStreamDefaultController]
    },
    type: null,
    size: null,
    boundary: null,
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: '[Internal URL]',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: {
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH',
      'cache-control': [Array],
      connection: 'close',
      'content-length': '1096',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      date: 'Wed, 17 Aug 2022 20:38:22 GMT',
      expires: 'Wed, 17 Aug 2022 20:38:21 GMT',
      'last-modified': 'Wed, 17 Aug 2022 20:38:21 GMT',
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      server: 'nginx/1.23.1',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains'
    },
    counter: 0,
    highWaterMark: 16384
  }
}
```

All of the examples I can find online look like they are doing something similar but are returning JSON data, where I have an empty body Response object. I would love any assistance.

When I attempt to hit the same url locally with a REST client like Postman I get a properly formatted JSON response like such:

```
  [
    {
        "id": 15,
        "salesforce_id": "0018Y00002fdzcyQAA",
        "applications": [
            {
                "id": 21,
                "salesforce_id": "0068Y00001BJkTEQA1",
                "salesforce_underwriting_id": "a008Y00000cSEfUQAW"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
```

Note: I am using the insecure agent for local development because I am using an nginx reverse proxy locally that has a self signed certificate and don't want to see the self signed certificate errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN's fetch docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json), fetch returns a response stream. You need to read it to completion. This can be done by calling the `.json()` function on the Response object returned from the fetch call. i.e.

```
const response = await fetch([URL]);
const salesData = await response.json();
```

`salesData` should have the same result as you'd see in postman.